# how to remove the freehub on a 2020 "Giant Two" hub from a CXR-1 wheelset?

Tags: giant

I've got a 2020 CXR-1 wheelset with a hub branded "Giant Two", and want to lube the freehub but it's not clear how to remove that. I haven't found any info about that hub. It doesn't seem to look like or disassemble like a DT 350, can't just pull off the cassette.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working on this hub is a bit scary since there is no info online about it. When I asked Giant tech support for info about the hub they sent me a drawing for a *different* hub and told me to just take it to a dealer if I had more questions. Also, it requires a 12 mm hex bit, a rare size that I've never needed to fix my bikes. Here are my notes, upvote if it helps. If you have a Giant road hub from about 2020 these steps *may* help you.

Tools needed: 19 mm round clamp (see below); 12 mm hex wrench (a hex bit socket is cheapest); 17 mm open end wrench; normal cassette removal tools; freehub grease

Steps:

1. Watch the DT Swiss channel's video

   . Once you get the end caps off, the hub internals of the Giant Two look like DT 370 3 pawl hubs (but there are no markings that say DT or 370).
2. Remove cassette
3. Remove left end cap. This is just held on by friction. You need to clamp it without damaging it, then gently pull off the axle. OD of the cap is 19.1 mm. I drilled a 3/4-inch diameter hole in a block of wood, then cut the block in half, put it on the end cap, clamped in a vise. Worked perfectly. Vise grips and lots of padding might work, go easy. [image: pic of end cap with wood clamp]
4. Remove right end cap. Put a 12 mm bit inside left side of axle. Put 17 mm open end wrench on right end cap. Turn it clockwise; it is left-hand threaded. See pic below that shows threads on axle.
5. Pull off freehub. It has 3 pawls, that stay attached when you remove the freehub.
   DT Swiss says to replace pawls and spring every year, but I don't know if their pawls and spring kit will fit or not. Replacing the pawls and spring would be fast and easy. I plan to do that in a year.
6. Clean and grease. DT recommends their Universal Grease on the pawls (NOT special grease, that's just for star ratchets), drive ring, axle, and end caps. I used Phil Wood Tenacious Oil, 1 drop per pawl, since it's recommended on several freehub posts. I dislike loud freehubs, so I put a thin coat of Phil Wood waterproof grease on the drive ring (yes, this is approved by DT Swiss, see the replies to comments on video above). Do not use a lot of grease or pawls won't engage and you may crash.[image: pic of axle & drive ring]
7. Reassemble. I torqued the right end cap to about 10 Nm. No idea if that's correct because Giant won't tell us.

My freehub is now smooooooth (was a bit gritty), and about 70% quieter.